# How to make object from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

How to assign array elements as object properties in PHP

```
$arr_zone_area = [];
foreach ($area as $key_area=>$row_area)
{
    foreach ($nominalRoll as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($row_area->ADMIN_ID == $value->AREA_ID)
        {
            $arr_zone_area[$key_area]['ZONE_NAME'] = $row_area->ZONE_NAME;
            $arr_zone_area[$key_area]['AREA_NAME'] = $row_area->AREA_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ZONE_NAME] => Dhaka
            [ADMIN_ID] => Admin Dhaka
        )

)
```

I want the output like this

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ZONE_NAME] => Dhaka
            [ADMIN_ID] => Admin Dhaka
        )

)
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the values to an object when you assign them in the loop:

```
$arr_zone_area[$key_area] = (object)['ZONE_NAME' => $row_area->ZONE_NAME,
                                     'AREA_NAME' => $row_area->AREA_NAME
                                    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSON encode and then decode it back, you will get the object. Something like this.

```
$obj_zone_area = json_decode(json_encode($arr_zone_area ));
```

now `$obj_zone_area` is a object.